# Convertir clase a json vba access

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

Buenas tardes amigos es que tengo un dilema tengo un modulo de clase en vba access y necesito convertirlo a json lo que he encontrado en web solo convierte palabras pero no clases, agrego ademas la clase encabezado.
estoy llenando las propiedades de la clase encabezado y convirtiéndolo a json pero aparece vació

```
Public id_factura As String
Public fecha As String
Public hora As String
Public nota As ArrayList
Public moneda As String
Public tipo_factura As Integer
Public metodo_de_pago As Integer
Public tipo_de_pago As Integer
Public identificador_de_pago As String
Public numero_resolucion_facturacion As String
Public fecha_vencimiento As String
Public numero_orden As String
Public prefijo As String



Public Property Get Getid_factura() As Variant
Getid_factura = id_factura
End Property

Public Property Let Setid_factura(ByVal idFactura As Variant)
id_factura = idFactura
End Property


Public Property Get Getfecha() As Variant
Getfecha = fecha
End Property

Public Property Let Setfecha(ByVal fecha As Variant)
fecha = fecha
End Property


Private Sub Comando11_Click()
Dim encabezado As Emcabezado
Set encabezado = New Emcabezado
Dim JsonItems As Collection
Set JsonItems = New Collection
Dim JsonDiccionario As Scripting.Dictionary
Set JsonDiccionario = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim idfac As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Facturas where IdFactura=1; ")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    idfac = rs("NumeroFactura")
    encabezado.id_factura = rs("NumeroFactura")
    encabezado.fecha = "2020-02-17"
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
MsgBox JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(encabezado)
End Sub
```

Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto que necesitas con la librería [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON), para convertir de forma sencilla desde y hacia Json, algo así:

```
MsgBox JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(encabezado, Whitespace:=2)
```

Para usarla sólo tienes que importar el .bas a tu proyecto y listo.
Suerte!

Comment: gracias por responder hice lo que sugeriste y el dialogo aparece vació aunque la clase encabezado tiene los datos

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la clase Emcabezado para verla, por favor?

Comment: la agregue en la pregunta por que comentario no podia agregar demasiados caracteres gracias

Comment: Me parece que el problema es que id_factura y fecha los tenés con variables públicas, y deberían ser propiedades.

Comment: osea que si las declaro private debería funcionar? voy a probar

Comment: No, como privado no, como propiedades públicas, o sea, con Public Property Let id_factura y Public Property Get id_factura.

Comment: así las tengo:
Public Property Let Setid_factura(ByVal idFactura As Variant)
id_factura = idFactura
End Property

Comment: Pero no debería llamarse Setid_factura, debería llamarse id_factura.